# problem in XMLSerializer when a string field value is space

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

using **XMLSerializer** for saving an object created from a class like myClass

```
Public Class MyClass
{
  Public String test = " " ;
}
```

will result :

```
<MyClass>
  <test> </test>
</MyClass>
```

but when I want to load the xml file looks like it's removing the white space ,which I need  .
How can I solve this problem ?
thanks

Comment: As that is a private field, the XML will be `<MyClass/>`... well, actually since it is a private *type*, it will just throw an exception...

Comment: sorry I just wanted to created a very simple example !!(it's fixed now :D)

Comment: I see your point, but it is usually better to provide the simplest example that **shows the problem** ;p

Comment: Show us what you do to "load the XML" which strips the whitespace! That's most likely the problem....

Comment: @marc_S :thanks you are right the problem was with my XML loading ,I used XmlReader and it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce - it seems fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("test")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        MyClass orig = new MyClass { Test = " " }, clone;
        using (var file = XmlWriter.Create("my.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(file, orig);
        }
        using (var file = XmlReader.Create("my.xml"))
        {
            clone = (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(file);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("'" + clone.Test + "'");
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("my.xml"));
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
' '
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001
/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><test> </test>
</MyClass>
```

It might help to be more specific about how you are trying to view it, such that it "looks like it's removing the white space".

Comment: I used XmlReader for loading the file and it's working now ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem when reading my XML file.  I haven't done work with XMLSerializer but when reading in an XML file as an XMLDocument set XMLDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true.